# Using wildcards in thunar search, search by pattern / bulk renamer

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xfce, thunar

Is it possible to use wildcards for searching for files / pattern?

Same question for the built in bulk renamer?

Comment: Not yet, https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7514